# Parse a JSON with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following type of JSON:

```
{
  "cards": [
    {
      "type": "Cultural",
      "number": "auto",
      "url": "http://www.url1.com"
    },
    {
      "type": "Museums",
      "number": "auto",
      "url": "http://www.url2.com"
    },
    {
      "type": "Outdoors",
      "number": "auto",
      "url": "http://www.url3.com"
    },
```

How can I with jQuery loop through my JSON please ?

Comment: What have you found out so far? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is your source object:

```
var data = {
  "cards": [
    {
      "type": "Cultural",
      "number": "auto",
      "url": "http://www.url1.com"
    },
    {
      "type": "Museums",
      "number": "auto",
      "url": "http://www.url2.com"
    },
    {
      "type": "Outdoors",
      "number": "auto",
      "url": "http://www.url3.com"
    }]
}
```

You do not need JQuery to loop through each item; with a simple `for` your can do it like

```
 for(var i=0; i<data.cards.length;i++){
    console.log(data.cards[i]);//<-- also possible: data.cards[i].type or data.cards[i].number or data.cards[i].url
 }
```

However, it is also possible to do it with JQuery using `.each`

```
$.each(data.cards, function(index, value) { 
  console.log(index + ': ' + value); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have already parsed it to JSON object then you can simply use following:

```
var j={"cards":[....]};

$.each(j.cards, function(i,c){ 
    //c is card that you can process.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a function which will parse well-formed json and return a javascript object:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

```
var json = '{"name":"John"}';
var myObject = $.parseJSON(json);
```

you could then use a javascript to loop through the object as such:

```
for(var ind in myObject) { 
   var value = myObject[ind]; 
}
```

in reality, you actually want to make sure that attribute is not a prototype, so change the above to:

```
for(var ind in myObject) { 
    if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(ind)) {
        var value = myObject[ind];
    }
}
```

or if you wanted an all jQuery solution you could use .each

```
$.each(myObject, function(ind, value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```